# Visual Studio 2010 Unit Testing - Any way to continue a TestMethod after failed assertion?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I have a test project in visual studio 2010. I have a TestMethod. Inside of this, I want to iterate over a list of things and test each. So, I have 1 test and want to assert N times (once for each item in the list).

However, I don't want to stop if one fails. I want to continue and then report all failures together.

Example:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
   foreach (item in list)
   {
      // if fail, continue on with the rest
      Assert(if fail, add to output list);
   }

   output_failures_all_at_once;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
// Assert that each item name is fewer than 8 characters.
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
   List<string> failures = new List<string>();

   // However you get your list in the first place
   List<Item> itemsToTest = GetItems(); 

   foreach (Item item in itemsToTest )
   {
      // if fail, continue on with the rest
      if (item.Name.Length > 8 )
      {
         failures.Add(item.Name);
      }
   }

   foreach (string failure in failures)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(failure);
   }

   Assert.AreEqual(0, failures.Count);
}
```

Comment: this doesn't assert per item though. can you explain the fail method?

Comment: You're right, it doesn't assert per item. The fail() method is what ever test you're doing. I'll re-write it to show a more explicit example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Tom's suggestion and instead of

```
foreach (string failure in failures)
{
   Console.WriteLine(failure);
}
```

do

```
var errorMessage = failures.Aggregate((current, next) => current + ", " + next);
Assert.AreEqual(0, failures.Count, errorMessage);
```

BTW the fail method is supposed to contain the logic that detects a failure in an item